# ¿Qué significa y de dónde proviene la palabra "funar"?

Tags: etimología, significado, coloquialismos, neologismos, jerga-internet

Recientemente he escuchado el uso frecuente del verbo *funar* en contextos coloquiales. Al tratar de investigar el origen, y definición, he adquirido la idea de que proviene de Chile. Una definición que recibí fue *sinónimo de matar o eliminar, por medio de una acción colectiva*.

Una amistad me comentó que aumentó en popularidad tras las protestas femeninas, donde utilizaron métodos de *doxeo*, para sacar a la luz a sus agresores.

¿Estoy equivocado en al creer que esta es la definición y origen de *funar*?

Formas en que lo he escuchado en mexicanos:

> Chale, lo funaron.
>
> Vamos a funar a *tal*.
>
> Simón, lo funaron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pues por lo que aparece en el *Diccionario de americanismos*, parece que las suposiciones de que proviene de Chile y que hace mención a una acción colectiva son correctas, mas no así la suposición del significado de "matar a alguien".

> **[funar(se)](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=funar)**
>
> III. 1. tr. *Ch*. Organizar actos públicos de denuncia contra organismos o personas relacionados con actos de represión delante de su sede o domicilio.

A juzgar por la definición, esto es lo que en España se viene conociendo como *hacer un [escrache](https://dle.rae.es/escrache)*. Se trata de una forma de protesta en la que un grupo de gente se establece delante de la casa de algún político o alto cargo como forma de protesta y presión para conseguir un determinado objetivo.

Por tanto, entiendo que en tu ejemplo de "vamos a funar a tal" lo que quiere decir no es que lo vayan a matar entre todos, sino que van a ir a esperarle a la puerta de su casa o lugar de trabajo para increparle, denunciarle, abuchearle, lo que sea.

Para más información, el Wikcionario provee [una definición](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/funar#:%7E:text=Efectuar%20un%20acto%20p%C3%BAblico%20de,%C3%81mbito%3A%20Chile.) similar pero con connotaciones ligeramente distintas:

> Efectuar un acto público de agravio y denuncia (una [funa](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=funa)), contra una persona o entidad que ha cometido una mala acción o un crimen, usualmente frente a su domicilio o sede. Ocasionalmente se efectúa en el lugar en el que se cometió un crimen.

Entiendo que este significado será el que ha llegado a México. Ahora bien, ignoro si allí el significado se ha ampliado y las protestas son de tal calibre que llegan a implicar la muerte del *funado*. Esto nos lo deberá aclarar alguien del país.

Answer (score 5):

Según la etimología remite a funa (abono, estiercol),  del mapuche (lengua región central y centro sur de Chile y Argentina): http://etimologias.dechile.net/?funa

Comment: Interesante porque pensaba en 'funar' como 'enlodar', (aunque el 'lodo' no es 'estiércol'), es decir, menoscabar la imagen del "funado" ante la opinión pública, fundada o infundadamente.

Answer (score 2):

Funar es una "denuncia publica" ante los actos de una persona o grupo. Algo así como un linchamiento social.

Comment: Es como un ajusticiamiento en la plaza pública.

Answer (score 1):

Yo la primera vez que oí esa palabra fue a principios del septiembre del 2020, cuando una Youtuber Virtual llamada Nimu causó una controversia, y varios querían "funarla". Al principio creía que esa palabra era de origen argentino, pero según la Real Academia Española es chileno.

Comment: Virtualmente sería: Boicotear, expulsar, aislar. Desacreditarla.

Answer (score 1):

Soy chilena, tengo 40 años, y desde que tengo memoria he usado la palabra "**funar**" que proviene del **mapudungun** (*lengua del pueblo Mapuche de la zona centro y sur de Chile*).

- "**Funa**", significa algo podrido, en mal estado, arruinado.

Cuando era niña, con mis amigos la usábamos en contextos como: "**funó el juego**", lo que quiere decir, "*arruinó el juego*". Posteriormente se comenzó a usar en contextos de denuncia pública, por ejemplo, hace 15 años se hizo una funa en contra del asesino de Víctor Jara, donde cientos de personas se manifestaron en contra del criminal para hacer justicia y de alguna manera "**arruinar**" su imagen social, ya que se hacía pasar por una persona decente.

Finalmente, con el auge de las redes sociales, hemos empezado a emplearla para referirnos a "*denuncias públicas de manera virtual*", lo que consiste en difundir ciertas pruebas (imágenes, videos, comentarios, conversaciones de chats, audios) que demuestran que alguien está mintiendo o actuando en perjuicio de los demás .

En Chile es muy común decir "*ayer **funaron** a ese hombre porque es un acosador*", "*están **funando** a esa mujer porque estafó a una persona*", etc.

Actualmente las mismas redes sociales han expandido el término chileno "**funar**" y posibilitado que este llegue hasta otros países para ser utilizado en este mismo contexto.